# Getting ID of SqlDataSource sender object

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource, sender-id

I'm trying to use a switch statement based on the ID of the object (sender).

```
        protected void SqlDataSource_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            int count = e.AffectedRows;
            SqlDataSource sqlds = (SqlDataSource)sender;
            switch (sqlds.ID)
            {
                case "sqldsPTY":
                    lblPTYCount.Text = "(" + count.ToString() + ")";
                    break;
                case "sqldsINC":
                    lblINCCount.Text = "(" + count.ToString() + ")";
                    break;
                ...
            }
         }
```

but I get the exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource'.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: For a way to solution, try; SqlDataSourceView sqlds = (SqlDataSourceView)sender;

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlDataSource sqlds = (SqlDataSource)sender;
```

is causing your issue - sender must be a SQLDataSourceView.  So try

```
SQLDataSourceView sqlds = (SQLDataSourceView)sender
```

and change the rest of code as appropriate one.

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx

Comment: sorry my mistake I didnt' use InnitCap on SQLDataSourceView. I found it now... But this doesn't seem to have an ID property, so how can I tell which datasource is the sender?

Comment: the msdn page says it does have an ID?  I'm not sure otherwise to be honest

Answer (score 0):

As was stated by @NDJ `sender` is `SQLDataSourceView`. The problem is how to get `SqlDataSource`.

`SqlDataSource` is passed to `SQLDataSourceView` constuctor ([MSDN: SqlDataSourceView Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ez9425kx(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx)). The problem is that it is stored only in private field `_owner` ([referencesource: SqlDataSourceView](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/SqlDataSourceView.cs,c55f34fd2e430c7c)). So it is necessary to use reflection to get it:

```
private string GetSqlDataSourceID(object sender)
{
    return (sender.GetType().GetField("_owner", BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
          BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(sender) as SqlDataSource).ID;
}
```